# Why lenient solves Unneccessary Stubbing exception in given example

Tags: java, testing, junit, junit5, spring-test

I have read previous questions but there is not exact answer pointing my questions directly. My code is below:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CityServiceImpl implements CityService {
    private final CityRepository cityRepo;
    private final CityMapper cityMapper;
@Override
public CityDto findById(Integer id) {
    City city = cityRepo.findById(id)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException(NotFoundException.Domain.CITY));
    return CityMapper.INSTANCE.cityToCityDto(city);

 }
}
```

My test class is as below:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class CityServiceTest {
  @Mock
  CityRepository cityRepository;

  @Mock
  CityMapper cityMapper;

  @InjectMocks
  CityServiceImpl cityService;
  City city;

  @BeforeEach
  public void init() {
    city = new City();
  }
  @Test
  void findById_Success() {
    Integer given = 1;

    CityDto expected = new CityDto();

    when(cityRepository.findById(1)).thenReturn(Optional.of(city));
    when(cityMapper.cityToCityDto(city)).thenReturn(expected);

    CityDto actual = cityService.findById(given);

    assertEquals(expected, actual);

  }
}
```

I  got an error pointing to this line

```
when(cityMapper.cityToCityDto(city)).thenReturn(expected);
```

**Unnecessary stubbings detected.
Clean & maintainable test code requires zero unnecessary code.
Following stubbings are unnecessary**

I got an aswer that when i use `lenient.when(cityMapper.cityToCityDto(city)).thenReturn(expected);` or annotation of lenient works fine. But what is the logic behind it.

Why lenient solves Unneccessary Stubbing exception in given example?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your mocked `cityMapper` is never being used, that’s why you see the exception.

Replace `CityMapper.INSTANCE` with `cityMapper` in the `findById` method and the `UnnecessaryStubbingException` should go away. If your code still does what it should, however, I cannot decide from what I see.

Answer (score 0):

The real dependency is CityMapper cityMapper. In findById_Success you are calling

```
cityMapper.cityToCityDto(city)
```

But, if you see the real method is not calling that . Instead

```
CityMapper.INSTANCE.cityToCityDto(city)
```

has been used.
Change any of them, it should work